# Getting "Can't set headers after they are sent" error on node js after send a post request in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

my problem is that I'm trying to send some posts requests in an angular loop.

This is my angular code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < response.length;i++) {
    response[i].pedido_id = $scope.pedidos.pedidoSeleccionado;
    PedidoDetalleFactory.save(
        {
            obraId: obra._id,
            pedidoId: response[i].pedido_id
        },
        response[i],
        function (result) {
            pedidosTransferidos++;
        },
        function (result) {
            // Handle error
        }
    );
}
```

And this is my node.js code

```
.post(Verify.verifyOrdinaryUser, function (req, res, next) {
    Servicios.findById(req.body.servicio_id).exec(function (err, servicio) {
        if (err) next(err);
        req.body.price = servicio.price;
        req.body.pedido_id = req.params.pedidoId;
        PedidoDetalles.create(
            req.body,
            function (err, pedido_detalle) {
                if (err) next(err);
                res.json(pedido_detalle);
            }
        );
    });
});
```

Everything looks fine, but I get this error

```
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:335:11)
```

Could this be happening beacause angular sends the request too fast to the server?

Please, help

Comment: This particular error occurs when you try to send more than one response to the same request.  The most common way this happens is with improper handling of async responses in your code (~99% of the time that's what causes it).  It has nothing to do with how fast someone makes requests of the server.

Comment: What does `Verify.verifyOrdinaryUser()` do?  Does it send a response to the request?

Comment: Is there a way I can make some Mongoose response sync instead of async to fix this problem?

Comment: No.  Mongoose is async.  You have to write your code properly to fix the problem.  Even if you could make it sync, you'd ruin the scalability and responsiveness of your server if you did so.  node.js is async for a reason.

Comment: @jfriend00 but then please tell me, is there a way to send a queue of requests and don't get back this error?

Comment: Yes, there's a way to do that, but I'd need to see more of your code to know where your problem is and what to suggest.  I don't think you've shown the offending code.

Comment: Verify.verifyOrdinaryUser() Is just a security middleware that ensures that the user is authenticated, But it have never cause any problem in the past, I think the problem could be that the next request come to the server before the previous request.

Comment: Multiple requests would only cause problems if you're mistakenly using shared variables where one request can stomp on the other rather than request-specific variables.  Again, we can't see your code to know.

Comment: But the server code looks fine, don't?

Comment: The server code certainly has a problem.  It is not correct.  For starters, `if (err) next(err);` should be `if (err) {return next(err);}` in all places that it occurs.  If that doesn't fix the problem, then the problem is likely in code you haven't shown us.

Comment: I'll try that, thank you

Comment: I was able to fix my code using `if (err) {return next(err);}` thank you

Comment: Do you understand why this fixes your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seem that you set header again after you had response to client. maybe you can try `if (err) {return next(err)}`, if error, please return, and don't exec the other codes.

Answer (score 0):

I was fetching some results in my server and then I was sending back a json with a attribute "_id" so mongoose was saying "This item already exists", but I couldn't debug the code because I had `if (err) next(err);` instead of `if (err) {return next(err);}`

Comment: Why are you filing your own answer, when chenkehxx has already file that same answer an hour ago?